# Stuck On firmware update after two days!

Tags: lg, device-firmware, lg-g-stylo

I got locked out of an account and I need my phone to verify myself. It was dead so I plugged it in. I tuned it in at about 7% and it said firmware update... this used to happen with my old phone and I’d usually take the battery out but this phone doesn’t have a removable battery so I let it die and decided to try again the next morning.

I plug it in again, this time at 2% just in case and oh wow it does the same thing and I even tried a different charger and plug location. I might be locked out from my phone and account forever because of this, what can I do?

Comment: I’m not trying to update it on purpose nor is it even plugged into a laptop, it’s plugged into the wall and doing this, is this normal? I tried to reset it and try again but it keeps doing it. I might be locked out for Awhile

Comment: Looks like there was an update waiting to install the last time you shut down the phone. You can try what happens if you hold key combinations like Poer+VolUp or Power+VolDown while starting/powering on. Try to fully charge the phone and then restart and let the update install.